# <scrcpy> adb server version () doesn't match this client ()

Tags: adb, scrcpy

I'm getting very contradicting messages trying to run scrcpy wirelessly.

```
$ adb connect 192.168.1.200:5555
connected to 192.168.1.200:5555
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.1.200:5555  device

$ scrcpy
scrcpy 1.24 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
* daemon started successfully
ERROR: Could not find any ADB device
ERROR: Server connection failed

$ scrcpy --tcpip
scrcpy 1.24 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
ERROR: Could not find any ADB device
ERROR: Server connection failed

$ adb devices
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
```

At some point I succeeded to connect and run scrcpy. I disconnected and tried to run it again but no luck this time. I can't wrap my head around what's causing this.

```
$ whereis adb
adb: /usr/bin/adb /usr/share/man/man1/adb.1.gz

$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

I connected via USB to reenable adb over TCP/IP. Device IP doesn't show up. Previously device ID and IP were listed.

```
$ scrcpy --tcpip
scrcpy 1.24 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
INFO: Switching device J6AXB763C036R6E to TCP/IP...
ERROR: Device IP not found
ERROR: Server connection failed
$ adb tcpip 5555
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
J6AXB763C036R6E device
```

I tried again and failed.

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
$ adb devices
List of devices attached

$ adb connect 192.168.1.200:5555
connected to 192.168.1.200:5555
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.1.200:5555  device

$ scrcpy
scrcpy 1.24 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
* daemon started successfully
ERROR: Could not find any ADB device
ERROR: Server connection failed
```

Comment: What output do you get by the command `/usr/bin/adb --version`? -> Please edit your question and add the output there not here in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some scrcpy distributions include an own adb version. If on your system adb is already present e.g. because you have installed Android SDK or a different tool that includes adb this can result in a adb version conflict as you have noticed.

To resolve this issue you can create the environment variable `ADB` and in it specify the path to the adb binary you want to use with scrcpy.

I assume on your system the newest adb version is the one installed to `/usr/bin/adb` so executing

```
export ADB=/usr/bin/adb
```

should solve your problem.

Windows users can do the same and add a new environment variable `ADB` that points to the latest `adb.exe` that should be used.

Comment: adb wasn't installed with scrcpy. Nevertheless, I've done what you suggested. Here is what happened.

Comment: $ export ADB=/usr/bin/adb 
$ adb connect 192.168.1.200:5555
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
* daemon started successfully
connected to 192.168.1.200:5555

Comment: $ scrcpy
scrcpy 1.24 <https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy>
exec: No such file or directory
ERROR: Command not found: [/usr/bin/adb], [start-server]
ERROR: (make 'adb' accessible from your PATH or define its fullpath in the ADB environment variable)
INFO: You may install 'adb' by "apt install adb"
ERROR: Could not execute "adb start-server"
ERROR: Could not start adb daemon
ERROR: Server connection failed

Comment: @Pavel But you have multiple adb versions present on your system. You should find them and only keep one adb version (usually the latest).

Comment: I can't find multiple versions. Only one.

Comment: I purged adb and now > $ adb connect 192.168.1.200:5555
bash: /usr/bin/adb: No such file or directory

Comment: @Pavel `adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39);` shows that you have one adb of version 41 and one version 39 installed. Find it e.g. using `find / -name adb 2> /dev/null`. And in your case I would keep the version installed via OS package manager.

Comment: ```$ find / -name adb 2> /dev/null
/usr/bin/adb
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/adb
/usr/share/doc/adb
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/adb
/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
/snap/scrcpy/386/usr/bin/adb
/snap/scrcpy/386/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
/snap/scrcpy/386/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/adb
/snap/scrcpy/386/usr/share/doc/adb
/snap/scrcpy/386/usr/share/lintian/overrides/adb```

Comment: Your scrcpy distribution contained adb as I told you: `/snap/scrcpy/386/usr/bin/adb` The environment variable may not work because of snap. Make sure you set the environment variable so that it is applied also inside a snap.

Comment: Robert, thank you very much! I reinstalled scrcpy, adb and android-sdk-platform-tools-common. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers who might have this problem and are using Ubuntu OS, do as @Robert said. You just have to:

1. Remove the one in the OS: `apt remove adb`
2. Then get the path of your adb: `which adb`
   For me, it was `/home/bilal/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb` because I had Android Studio installed
3. Then `export ADB=/home/bilal/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`
4. And voila, `scrcpy` should work

Comment: don't have enough reputation to upvote @Robert answer, incase your are wondering why i didn't